# How to set up server to be accessed from mobile devices

Tags: mysql, android

I need to set up a server that will eventually be accessed from an Android application. I don't have experience with how to go about this, but I've seen MySQL servers (Amazon EC2). I would need to store data on the server remotely (again, from a mobile device) and fetch it to display. What would be the best kind of server to use? I'm guessing I would only need around 50 GB of space.

Is it possible to use a network drive and set that up as a remote server with an IP address?

I would need to upload and extract data through java on Android. This is my first question on ServerFault, and I'm not sure if it's the appropriate forum. If not, please redirect me.

Comment: Please give reason for downvote; I am new to this website. Where could I ask such a question?

Comment: The phrasing of your question indicates that you're likely in fairly far over your head. Servers run services and applications. Mobile devices do not "access servers" they use an application or service that may or may not be optimized for mobile devices. As Lucas said, go hire a professional.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest by starting to learn how basic server management works, using a a network drive that can connect to "wifi" <--- makes most sysadmins tow curl. Further more your question is on the border with product recommendation (off topic)

The best way to do this is to use a serverside application that can present your data to a phone. So your best bet is to store your data in some sort of database. Your server can then react to a request (for instance you make a POST request and it returns you some JASON you can interpret on the phone).

The best advice I can give you:

**Don't do it, hire a professional**

Comment: Can I set up a database by simply buying a Windows Server and installing MySQL on it?

Comment: Without trying to be rude, it won't be done 'simply' if you have to ask that question. I strongly suggest you first take a long time learning how basic server management works. If you set up a server badly, you risk getting hacked and private data stolen. If this is user data, then in most countries you can be hold liable personally.